# How can I use ssh with python and linux to connect to windows and run commands?

Tags: python, unix, ssh, paramiko

I wrote a generic script on Python that supports Windows and Unix ssh connection from Unix.

When I try Unix command from Unix to create dir in Windows, I get exit 53

```
/usr/bin/ssh2 --password pass -l admin ip_address mkdir "C:\Temp\ALEX_TEST_EX" &
```

When I write only `/usr/bin/ssh2 --password pass -l admin ip_address`, it is Ok. I login to Windows

When I try `C:\Temp\ALEX_TEST_EX` on this machine manually it is also Ok.

What is problem?

I also try to use with Python ssh2 command like

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect("ip_address", username="admin", password="pass")
```

but I get exceptions

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 402, in connect
>     self, server_hostkey_name, server_key
>   File "/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 768, in missing_host_key
>    'Server {!r} not found in known_hosts'.format(hostname)
> paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Server 'X.Y.Z.W' not found in known_hosts
> ```

Comment: `ssh.connect("ip_address", username="admin", password="pass")` you are not passing IP address ? are you have it in a variable ?

Comment: I pass string of ip or hostname @SandeepLade

Answer (score 1):

You have not configued the client machine to allow you to *know* the server you are trying to connect to.  You can either configure the client, or as a work around you can set the [`MissingHostKeyPolicy`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html) on paramiko like:

#### Code:

To warn when host not in known hosts:

```
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy)
```

To auto add host to know hosts:

```
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
```

#### Full Code:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy)

ssh.connect("localhost", username="admin", password="pass")
```

Comment: How can I create dir on remote machine with ssh python command ? @Stephen Rauch

Comment: @Alex This is not a chat. If you have a new question, post it separately.

Comment: It is my original goal. I posted in on my question. @MartinPrikryl

Comment: Your problem had nothing to do with creating a folder. You could not even connect!